# What happens if an object is modified outside of the concurrent map in java?

Tags: java, concurrency

What happens if an object is modified outside of the concurrent map in java?

Say, I have a concurrent hash map and in one thread I retrieve a value from that map and modify its state. Will the other threads see the modification without an additional synchronization?

Comment: Unless the object makes guarantees about the visibility of its state (say, it's another concurrent hash map), you need external synchronization.

Comment: yes, concurrent hash map watches over addition and removal of elements, but it doesn't make the elements immutable.

Comment: @NathanHughes I was thinking about it, I am not sure if the state of the modified object will be visible to the other threads.
Should the fields of the object be thread-safe? For instance, I have a several independent fields long fields. Should I use volatile for those fields or AtomicLong then?

Comment: The words, "outside of the map" don't mean anything. The object was never _in_ the map. So-called "container" classes in Java don't actually contain objects. They only contain _references_ to objects. The only thing in Java that truly contains objects is the heap.  So your question really boils down to this: "If I get a reference to an object, and then I change the object, will other threads see the change?" Both Andy Turner's answer and Burak Serdar's answer (below) speak to that question.

Comment: Yeah, I know that they contain references only. I still do not know if I need to mark my fields volatile or convert them to AtomicLong.

Answer (score 4):

The key concept in the Java Memory Model is the *happens before* relation. You can only rely on things happening between threads if there is a happens before relationship between the two of them.

In the case of `ConcurrentHashMap`, there is a happens-before relationship between a put and a subsequent get of the value for the same key: updating the value and putting it into the map *happens before* getting the value and reading its state. Because of that happens before relationship, the update happens before the reading of the state, so you will see the updated state.

So, if you update the state of an object, and then put it into the map, if you subsequently get it from the map, you are guaranteed to see that updated state (until such time as you put again).

But, if you have a reference to that object outside the context of a `ConcurrentHashMap`, there is no automatic happens-before relationship. You have to create that relationship for yourself.

One way of doing this is with synchronization (as in using `synchronized`, on the same object in all threads); other ways include:

- writing and reading a `volatile` variable
- using a `Lock`
- putting the object into the map again, and then getting from the map before you start using it in the other thread.

Comment: can I use ConcurrentMap.compute() instead of modifying my object outside of the map context? Will the state of my object be visible to the other threads? Should I do an extra synchronization for the fields of such object?

Comment: @IhorM. What is "it"? If you mean to do the update, yes: the state you put in the compute call *happens before* you get it in another thread.

Comment: @IhorM. `compute` is logically just a get and a put call, wrapped so they are performed atomically. So if there is a happens before relationship between put and get, it's still there with compute.

Comment: I never heard about "happens-before" relationship. Nevertheless, I still do not know if I need to do an extra synchronization for the visibility of the values of that said object.
Let's say I have several longs inside of that object and I am modifying them with the use of `merge`, which is an atomic operation. Should I make those longs as volatile? Should I use AtomicLong?

Comment: @AndyTurner `compute` is performed atomically in respect to other `compute` calls, not regarding `get`. That wouldn’t work. Just consider: Thread A calls `get` and retrieves a reference to a value. Thread B calls `compute` with the same key and starts manipulating the stored object, Thread A processes the object it retrieved via `get` while thread B is manipulating it…

Comment: @Holger that's not what I said: I said that because a `compute` call is a composition of a `get` and a `put`, then there is a happens-before between the `put` done by the `compute` and a subsequent `get`.

Comment: Which would be meaningless if the OP modifies the already stored object. Which is precisely what they are trying to do.

Comment: I still do not know if I need to mark my fields as `volatile` in order to achieve visibility amongst different threads. If thread A modifies my object and then when thread B fetches it after thread A completed the modification, will it see the change that was made to my object?

Comment: @IhorM. how does thread B know whether thread A completed the modification? When you modify objects already stored in the map, there's no guaranty about it and even declaring all fields `volatile` might be insufficient. An object's state consist of all its properties and the constraints for a consistent state may incorporate more than one variable. Declaring the variables `volatile` does not preclude changes between two read operations.

Comment: In my case, the variables that constitute the object's state are independent of each other. So, there is no need to synchronize on the object itself when one of the fields is modified. So, in my case `volatile` seems like a winner.
But also, I can make several changes to those fields within an atomic `compute` call on my concurrent map. In that case, it seems to me having `volatile` is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no.

A concurrent map will only synchronize the access to the map. That is, if one thread writes the map, all other threads can see that without additional synchronization.

If you retrieve an object from the map and modify it without synchronization, and if another thread retrieves the same object to read it, then you have a race without explicit synchronization between those threads.

Comment: What are you saying? That the retrieved object must be thread-safe itself?

Comment: Yes, if the object is mutable, you need to synchronize the access to the object itself. Just because it came from a synch map doesn't make the object thread-safe. Only the map is thread safe, not the objects in it.

Comment: What if I use `compute()` method for it as it was suggested above? That's an atomic operation, my object will modified within a remapping function. How about the visibility of its fields? Do other threads will see the change? I am just looking for the most elefant solution here.

Comment: synchronize the access using the object you got from the map. That's the cheapest solution. use synchronized(obj) {...} when reading/writing the object where obj is the object from the map.

Comment: synchronization is an easy answer, I am loioking for a more robust approach via new atomic methods of concurrent map.

Comment: @IhorM., I think Burak misunderstood. An object does not have to be "thread-safe" in order for thread A to see the change after thread B updates the object. But you do have to _somehow_ establish that chain of "happens-before" releationships between the two events. (see Andy Turner's answer.) A "thread-aware" object could, itself provide the means to establish that link, or you could rely on other means, external to the object itself.  (E.g., It would be sufficient if there was some mutex, and each of the two threads accessed the object only while keeping the mutex locked.)

Comment: Ok, but if I use a concurrent map and I will manipulate my object's state ONLY within an atomic operation (like `compute` and `merge`), the concurrent map itself will do an internal locking on such an object. 
If thread A started modification of my object within an atomic operation, thread B cannot access it while thread A is performing an operation, can it? 
Then, after thread A completed the update atomically, thread B will see an updated state of an object without an additional synchronization or making my variables `volatile`.

Comment: So, if I do not longer modify objects outside of the concurrent map and utilize the atomic update, I should be able to solve visibility problem without an additional synchronization, right?